# AngularJS can't get months dropdown to display in Proper order Jan-Dec order

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I have tried to use below solution to display months in order from Jan-Dec but facing some problem. I am getting data from service in JSON format.

ng-model="month" ng-options="currMonth for currMonth in months"

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking..please add more code...what you have tried so far..

Comment: Hi Pankaj - I am having drop down that displaying months like Feb, Jan, Mar, April, Dec..... Currently it's not in order. I would like to display in order. I am getting data from service in object format. Please let me know how I can display it in order like Jan, Feb, Mar etc.

Comment: please try to reproduce with plunkr & add more description & code to the question